# How to change ion-range color dynamically in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to change the color of an `ion-range` from `TypeScript` while it is dragging. So that for example it changes color when passing certain values.

I know a custom color can be set via `variables.scss`, But I can't find out whether this can be changed later from `TypeScript`.

Comment: What about my answer ? is it not what you want?

Comment: This was exactly what I was hoping for -- many many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can catch `ionChange event` of `ion-range` to change its colour dynamically.**

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-range [color]="color" min="1" max="100" pin="true"
          [(ngModel)]="number" 
          (ionChange)="onRangeChangeHandler()">
    <ion-icon range-left small name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
export class HomePage {

number: number;
color: string;
  constructor() {

  }

  onRangeChangeHandler() {

    if (this.number > 0 && this.number < 26) {
        this.color = 'dark';
    }
    else if (this.number > 25 && this.number < 51) {
      this.color = 'primary';
    }
    else if (this.number > 50 && this.number < 76) {
      this.color = 'secondary';
    }
    else {
      this.color = 'danger';
    }
  }
}
```

**Find working [StackbBlitz Example Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-ionic-ion-range-color-dynamically)**